# Firebase cloud functions: is `createId()` available on the server side?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

If I want to write to the database from my client side, I can inject an `AngularFirestore` instance and generate an id automatically using `createId()`:

```
const individualId = this.angularFirestore.createId();
```

But if I want to do the same thing in a cloud function, using the Firestore admin API, I can't find an equivalent operation. I can create a Firestore instance in a cloud function by running

```
const db = admin.firestore();
```

However, the object that is created has no `createId()` function available.

Is there an equivalent to `createId()` that I can use within a cloud function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand from this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2323) and this [article](https://medium.com/avocoders/getting-started-with-angularfirestore-1a2cef8aa394) that "`AngularFirestore.createId()` generates a new id from a symbolic collection named '_'".

If you want to mimic this behaviour in a Cloud Function, you could use the [`doc()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#doc) method of a [`CollectionReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html) without specifying any path. You will get a [`DocumentReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html), and then you can use the `id` property to get the "last path element of the referenced document".

Something like the following:

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const docRef = db.collection('_').doc();
const newId = docRef.id;
```

---

Note that, as explained in the issue referred to above, it is a bit weird to "use a generic collection instead of an actual collection" to generate an id, because you would normally use the collection in which you want to create a new Document. But this is not a problem, according to this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2323#issuecomment-584358807) from James Daniels (who is a Firebaser), since the Firestore auto-generated ID is "just a random string and doesn't take the path into consideration at all".

Comment: Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

in JavaScript, for the new Firebase 9 (January 2022). In my case I am developing a comments section:

```
const commentsReference = await collection(database, 'yourCollection');
await addDoc(commentsReference, {
  ...comment,
  id: doc(commentsReference).id,
  date: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
});
```

Wrapping the collection reference (`commentsReference`) with the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) provides an identifier (`id`)